# Removing component at index 0 remove all item

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have a component inside a loop, and a remove button per component.

If I remove components at index 1 and above, it is removing fine, but when I remove an item at index 0 (first one), all of the components disappear but the data is still available in the Vue console.

```js
//form.vue
<template>
  <div>
    <div
      v-for="(item, index) in items"
      :key="index"
    >
      <viewer
        :item="item"
        :index="index"
        @removed="remove"
      ></viewer>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
import default {
  //truncated
  data() {
    items: ['sample 1', 'sample 2', 'sample 3']
  },
  methods: {
    remove(index) {
      this.items.splice(index,1)
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

```js
//viewer.vue
<template>
  <div>
    <div>{{ item }}</div>
    <div @click="remove()">Remove</div>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
import default {
//tuncated
  props: {
    item,
    index
  },
  methods: {
    remove() {
      this.$emit("removed", this.index)
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several errors:

1. `v-for` should be written like this:

```
<div
      v-for="(item, index) in items"
      :key="index"
>
```

2. `props` should be defined like this:

```
props: ["item", "index"],
```

3. `data()` should be written like this:

```
data() {
    return {
         items: ["sample 1", "sample 2", "sample 3"]
    };
},
```

Comment: I simplified the code posted here, it contains all the important part I think is needed/having bugs. I do not see these error on the real code though.

And it is working perfectly except for the remove part

Comment: I tested your code and it worked after fixing the above issues. If you have any other errors, feel free to provide a fiddle with your code